# Is a TestNG data provider parameter in setUp method possible?

Tags: testng

I have some init statements that need to be done with the data provider parameter and  would want to access the data provider parameter value in the `@BeforeMethod` setup method.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 22):

Yes, its totally possible.  In the `@BeforeMethod`  annotated method, you can pass an optional built-in argument of Object[]  that is basically a copy of the parameters being passed to the `@Test` method.  In my case, I pass 2 args to my test method:

```
@Test(dataProvider="provider")
public void doTest( TestHelper testHelper, Map<String,String> paramMap ) {
   ....
```

So, something like this (and it doesn't need to be a factory DataProvider) :

```
@BeforeMethod
public void setUp( Object[] testArgs ) {
    Map<String,String> paramMap = (Map<String, String>)testArgs[1];
    TestHelper testHelper = testArgs[0];
    String testName = paramMap.get( "testCaseName" );
    log.logTcStep( "Test case name: " + testName );
    log.setLogTcName( testName );
    testHelper.setTestName( testName );
    testHelper.setTagsByString( paramMap.get( "browser" ) );
    testHelper.setBuildNumber( paramMap.get( "environment" ) );
}
```

Comment: Don't underestimate the power of TestNG!

Comment: @djangofan - Thanks. I am using this answer to prepare my tests. But, have a new hurdle. Could you please help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52575316/testng-how-to-run-cleanup-code-after-a-test-method-is-run-for-all-data-provide

Comment: @djangofan - How do I import the TestHelper class ? Intellij IDEA can't find it. Which library do I need to us for this ?

Comment: @testerjoe2 - TestHelper is a class that might do anything, depending on what you need, such as get configuration from a .properties file.

Answer (score -3):

No there is not.

The proper way is to use @Factory and to create an instance of your test class for each set of data, as described here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/testng-users/3Kny3qTVdmg