# Testng - How to run cleanup code after a test method is run for all data providers?

Tags: java, testng

I have a testng test (below) where I use one value of "totalAmount" for each array given by the data provider "junkDP". I want to reset "totalAmount", ONLY after "test" method has run for each array in "junkDP". Is this possible in testng ? How to do it ?

Please note that @AfterMethod & @AfterTest do not do what I want. @AfterMethod resets "totalAmount" before "test" method is run for each array after the first array in "junkDP". @AfterTest is run after the @AfterClass.

**The code:**

```
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.*;

public class JUNKdP {

    @DataProvider( name = "junkDP")
    public static Object[][] junkDP() {
        Object [] [] dataSet = new Object[][] {
                new Object[] {1, 2},
                new Object[] {3, 4},
                new Object[] {5, 6}};
        return dataSet;
    }

}


public class JUNK {

    private int totalAmount = 0;

    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClass(){System.out.println("BeforeClass\n");}

    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod(){
        System.out.println("BeforeMethod\n");
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void afterMethod(){
        System.out.println("AfterMethod\n");
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void afterTest(){
        System.out.println("AfterTest\n");
        this.totalAmount = 0;
        System.out.println("Reset total amount to 0");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void afterClass(){System.out.println("AfterClass\n");}

    @Test(dataProvider = "junkDP", dataProviderClass = JUNKdP.class, enabled = true)
    public void test(int a, int b){
        System.out.println("Test method");
        int sum = a + b;
        System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
        this.totalAmount = this.totalAmount + sum;
        System.out.println("totalAmount: " + this.totalAmount + "\n");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
BeforeClass

BeforeMethod

Test method
Sum: 3
totalAmount: 3

AfterMethod

BeforeMethod

Test method
Sum: 7
totalAmount: 10

AfterMethod

BeforeMethod

Test method
Sum: 11
totalAmount: 21

AfterMethod

AfterClass

AfterTest

Reset total amount to 0
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to set the instance variable totalAmount to 0 after a test finishes.   The test will just get garbage collected when its done.  The DataProvider should be creating a isolated thread for each row of data OR you can try setting threads in a testng.xml suite file.  you can see that with a println of Thread.getName .   In other words, its not clear to me why you want to set the variable to 0 after test is finished.

Comment: @djangofan - "You shouldn't need to set the instance variable totalAmount to 0 after a test finishes.". I did not post the actual code here. I posted a representation of what my code looks like. Sorry for the confusion. In my actual code, I delete a REST resource instead of resetting totalAmount. But, imagine that we needed to reset totalAmount. Then, how would we do it ?

Comment: Sorry, not enough context.  If I take a guess then define your Rest resource as a Spring bean "prototype" and then i think each TestNG thread will have a copy that can be garbage collected after thread closes.  Right?   It's a matter of understanding object scope within the thread.   I know that doesnt answer your question about testNG ordering of calls..

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the question, you are searching for executor after the test method ?

...if yes, depending on the test runner

here you go, how testng is doing it:

> http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations

@AfterTest or @AfterMethod

Comment: Inferno - I updated my question and put some working code there instead of a vague example. "@AfterTest" & "@AfterMethod" do not do what I need.